# Do Until TryCast System.NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple "bug", but it seems that I cannot figure it out.
I'm reading an excel file (.xls) using ExcelLibrary, and I have a Do Loop, to go through my file. At the end of the file (my last row with data), the condition should be true and the loop should stop. 
Here is my issue: I get this error when the loop reaches my last row : "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my code:

```
Try
    Do Until TryCast(WS.Cells(ws_Row, 2).Value.ToString, String) = Nothing

        ' Get data into a data table
        ws_Row = ws_Row + 1

    Loop
Catch ex As Exception
    LBL_ERR.Text = ex.ToString
    LBL_ERR.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

This should be so simple to accomplish, yet I get this error message
PS. The error I receive is at the row with the Do Until row

Comment: PS. I've put the loop into a Try Catch, because this way I can keep the data stored in the DataTable, and continue the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Do Until WS.Cells(ws_Row, 2).Value Is Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tired that. Same error message.